# How can I get a value of instance which is already set in another class?

Tags: java, object, instance

I'm a new to Java. I have 3 classes: 1-DataHolder 2-SetToDateHolder 3-GetFromDataHolder; In the "SetToDateHolder" class, I set the value to dataholder object, and I trying to access it in the "GetFromDataHolder" class, but it got null value, I know it happens because of new instance created. Can you help me to realize that I can get the value of instance which I have set in another class.

These are the classes:

```
public class DataHolder {

    private String myName;

    public String getMyName() {
        return myName;
    }

    public void setMyName(String myName) {
        this.myName = myName;
    }
}

public class SetToDataHolder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataHolder dataHolder = new DataHolder();
        dataHolder.setMyName("Wesley");
    }

}

public class GetFromDataHolder{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataHolder dataHolder = new DataHolder();
        System.out.println(dataHolder.getMyName());
    }

}
```

Comment: those two DataHolder instances are not related to each other. If you want to set a value for all the instances, use a static variable. But, this isn't just in another method, it's in another application, so to speak.

Comment: Please show exactly how you are running your code.

Comment: @tgdavies they are both main methods, I think it's fairly clear how he runs them.

Comment: Each time you run a JVM, with `java SetToDataHolder` or `java GetFromDataHolder` you are starting with a 'blank slate'. No objects you created in a previous process will exist in the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why you need 2 additional classes as you already have the getter / setter in your DataHolder class, but here's how you should be able to proceed your logic:

```
public class DataHolder {

    private String myName;

    public String getMyName() {
        return myName;
    }

    public void setMyName(String myName) {
        this.myName = myName;
    }
}

public class SetToDataHolder {
    
    private DataHolder dataHolder;

    public SetToDataHolder(DataHolder dataHolder){
        this.dataHolder = dataHolder;
    }

    public void setMyName(String myName) {
        this.dataHolder.setMyName(myName);
    }
}

public class GetFromDataHolder{
    
    private DataHolder dataHolder;

    public GetFromDataHolder(DataHolder dataHolder){
        this.dataHolder = dataHolder;
    }

    public String getMyName() {
        this.dataHolder.getMyName();
    }
}

public class MainClass{
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DataHolder dataHolder = new DataHolder();

        SetToDataHolder setToDataHolder = new SetToDataHolder(dataHolder);
        setToDataHolder.setMyName("Wesley");

        GetFromDataHolder getFromDataHolder = new GetFromDataHolder(dataHolder);
        System.out.println(getFromDataHolder.getMyName());
    }
}
```

The idea is that your SetToDataHolder and GetFromDataHolder, have access to the same instance of DataHolder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I am verifying data from database. So I need dataHolder holds the data in SetToDataHolder class then I get the data in another class and compare with original data for assertion. I just want to do it in different class without using third party recorder like Excel or CVS file. Is that possible to do so?

Comment: In this case, i would indeed have 3 classes, one named "Entity" (to hold the data fetched from the database), one named "EntityDAO" (to fetch the data from the database and returns a List<Entity>), , and one last class named "DataIntegrityChecker" (to verify the fetched entities with a specific method verify(List<Entity> entities)). This is an example and you're free to think of another approach. DAO is a conventional name for classes that are used to fetch data from a datasource. Entity is a conventional name for a class that holds a data, and the other class is the fruit of my imagination.